# Reference in B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions missing in Identity Experience Framework examples

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

I'm getting an error when uploading my customized policy, which is based on Microsoft's SocialAccounts example ([tenant] is a placeholder I added):

```
Policy "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" of tenant "[tenant].onmicrosoft.com" makes a reference to ClaimType with id "client_id" but neither the policy nor any of its base policies contain such an element
```

I've done some customization to the file, including adding local account signon, but comparing copies of `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml` in the examples, I can't see where this element is defined.  It is not defined in `TrustFrameworkBase.xml`, which is where I would expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, although it doesn't make sense to me.  Hopefully this helps someone else running into the same issue.

The `TrustFrameworkBase.xml` is not the same in each scenario.  When Microsoft documentation said not to modify it, I assumed that meant the "base" was always the same.  The implication of this design is: If you try to mix and match between scenarios then you also need to find the supporting pieces in the `TrustFrameworkBase.xml` and move them into your extensions document.  It also means if Microsoft does provide an update to their reference policies and you want to update, you need to remember which one you implemented originally and potentially which other ones you had to pull from or do line-by-line comparison.  Not end of the world, but also not how I'd design an inheritance structure.

This also explains why I had to work through previous validation errors, including missing `<DisplayName>` and `<Protocol>` elements in the `<TechnicalProfile>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - I agree that is a problem.

My suggestion is always to use the "SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa" scenario as the sample.

That way you will always have the correct attributes and you know which one to use if there is an update.

It's easy enough to comment out the MFA stuff in the user journeys if you don't want it.

There is one exception. If you want to use "username" instead of "email", the reads/writes etc. are only in the username sample.